# How to make automatic selection with a hidden element

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress-based website and posting on it requires subscription plan selection, which is part of the theme that's used. However, I don't intend on implementing different subscription plans and there would be only one free plan, so manual selection from the users is not needed. This is the code of the plan selection option that gets shown to the user when posting:

```
<li <?php echo $class_select; ?> data-sku="<?php echo $package->sku ?>" data-id="<?php echo $package->ID ?>" data-price="<?php echo $package->et_price; ?>"
    <?php if( $package->et_price ) { ?>
        data-label="<?php printf(__("You have selected: %s", ET_DOMAIN) , $package->post_title ); ?>"
    <?php } else { ?>
        data-label="<?php _e("You are currently using the 'Free' plan", ET_DOMAIN); ?>"
    <?php } ?>
 >
    <span class="price">
        <?php if( $package->et_price ) {
            ae_price($package->et_price);
        }else {
            _e("Free", ET_DOMAIN);
        } ?>
    </span>
    <span class="title-plan">
        <span class="package-title"><?php echo $package->post_title .' - '; ?></span>
        <span class="package-limit"><?php if($text) { echo $text; } ?></span>
        <span><?php echo $package->post_content; ?></span>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-submit-price-plan select-plan"><?php _e( 'Select' , ET_DOMAIN ); ?></a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</li>
```

I think the way to go would be to make it so that it automatically selects the one available for selection plan and hide this element from the user, so that he doesn't actually see all this and save him one step when posting. I'm not really sure how this could be accomplished, though - do you have any ideas or suggestions?

I've been developing this website for the last 4 months and this is the very last thing remaining before its completion and then it would be ready to launch. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.